# syntax highlighting for files without extensions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting, file-extension

I am working an some library headers that do not have a `.h` or `.hpp` extension. Visual Studio does not give me syntax highlighting and other features for those files. Is there any way to turn them on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it. In the German version of Visual Studio, the option can be found under "Extras / Optionen  /Text-Editor / Dateierweiterung / [x] Dateien ohne Erweiterung zuordnen zu: Microsoft Visual C++".

Comment: "Tools/Options/Text Editor/File Extension/[x]Map extensionless files to: Microsoft Visual C++" :-)

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2015:

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension:
>
> Map extensionless files to: < Microsoft Visual C++ >

[image]